# How to fix DeprecationWarning: Buffer()

Tags: node.js, azure

I am building a web app from a sample I found, and get a warning in my output "DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead."

In the package-lock.json file it refers to safer-buffer, which from my research is what is used to upgrade the buffer, however I am assuming this may be causing the issue. Here are the parts of the file which refer to buffer:

```
    "asn1": {
      "version": "0.2.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/-/asn1-0.2.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jxwzQpLQjSmWXgwaCZE9Nz+glAG01yF1QnWgbhGwHI5A6FRIEY6IVqtHhIepHqI7/kyEyQEagBC5mBEFlIYvdg==",
      "requires": {
        "safer-buffer": "~2.1.0"
      }

   "bl": {
      "version": "2.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bl/-/bl-2.2.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-wbgvOpqopSr7uq6fJrLH8EsvYMJf9gzfo2jCsL2eTy75qXPukA4pCgHamOQkZtY5vmfVtjB+P3LNlMHW5CEZXA==",
      "requires": {
        "readable-stream": "^2.3.5",
        "safe-buffer": "^5.1.1"
      }

  "buffer-equal-constant-time": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-equal-constant-time/-/buffer-equal-constant-time-1.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-+OcRMvf/5uAaXJaXpMbz5I1cyBk="
    },

 "ecc-jsbn": {
      "version": "0.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ecc-jsbn/-/ecc-jsbn-0.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-OoOpBOVDUyh4dMVkt1SThoSamMk=",
      "requires": {
        "jsbn": "~0.1.0",
        "safer-buffer": "^2.1.0"
      }
    },


    "ecdsa-sig-formatter": {
      "version": "1.0.11",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ecdsa-sig-formatter/-/ecdsa-sig-formatter-1.0.11.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-nagl3RYrbNv6kQkeJIpt6NJZy8twLB/2vtz6yN9Z4vRKHN4/QZJIEbqohALSgwKdnksuY3k5Addp5lg8sVoVcQ==",
      "requires": {
        "safe-buffer": "^5.0.1"
      }
    },

    "express": {
      "version": "4.16.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.16.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-j12Uuyb4FMrd/qQAm6uCHAkPtO8FDTRJZBDd5D2KOL2eLaz1yUNdUB/NOIyq0iU4q4cFarsUCrnFDPBcnksuOg==",
      "requires": {
        "accepts": "~1.3.5",
        "array-flatten": "1.1.1",
        "body-parser": "1.18.3",
        "content-disposition": "0.5.2",
        "content-type": "~1.0.4",
        "cookie": "0.3.1",
        "cookie-signature": "1.0.6",
        "debug": "2.6.9",
        "depd": "~1.1.2",
        "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
        "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
        "etag": "~1.8.1",
        "finalhandler": "1.1.1",
        "fresh": "0.5.2",
        "merge-descriptors": "1.0.1",
        "methods": "~1.1.2",
        "on-finished": "~2.3.0",
        "parseurl": "~1.3.2",
        "path-to-regexp": "0.1.7",
        "proxy-addr": "~2.0.4",
        "qs": "6.5.2",
        "range-parser": "~1.2.0",
        "safe-buffer": "5.1.2",
        "send": "0.16.2",
        "serve-static": "1.13.2",
        "setprototypeof": "1.1.0",
        "statuses": "~1.4.0",
        "type-is": "~1.6.16",
        "utils-merge": "1.0.1",
        "vary": "~1.1.2"
      }

    "iconv-lite": {
      "version": "0.4.23",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.4.23.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-neyTUVFtahjf0mB3dZT77u+8O0QB89jFdnBkd5P1JgYPbPaia3gXXOVL2fq8VyU2gMMD7SaN7QukTB/pmXYvDA==",
      "requires": {
        "safer-buffer": ">= 2.1.2 < 3"
      }
    },

    "jwa": {
      "version": "1.4.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jwa/-/jwa-1.4.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-qiLX/xhEEFKUAJ6FiBMbes3w9ATzyk5W7Hvzpa/SLYdxNtng+gcurvrI7TbACjIXlsJyr05/S1oUhZrc63evQA==",
      "requires": {
        "buffer-equal-constant-time": "1.0.1",
        "ecdsa-sig-formatter": "1.0.11",
        "safe-buffer": "^5.0.1"
      }
    },


    "jws": {
      "version": "3.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jws/-/jws-3.2.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-YHlZCB6lMTllWDtSPHz/ZXTsi8S00usEV6v1tjq8tOUZzw7DpSDWVXjXDre6ed1w/pd495ODpHZYSdkRTsa0HA==",
      "requires": {
        "jwa": "^1.4.1",
        "safe-buffer": "^5.0.1"
      }
    },

    "mysql": {
      "version": "2.16.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql/-/mysql-2.16.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-dPbN2LHonQp7D5ja5DJXNbCLe/HRdu+f3v61aguzNRQIrmZLOeRoymBYyeThrR6ug+FqzDL95Gc9maqZUJS+Gw==",
      "requires": {
        "bignumber.js": "4.1.0",
        "readable-stream": "2.3.6",
        "safe-buffer": "5.1.2",
        "sqlstring": "2.3.1"
      }
    },

    "readable-stream": {
      "version": "2.3.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-2.3.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-tQtKA9WIAhBF3+VLAseyMqZeBjW0AHJoxOtYqSUZNJxauErmLbVm2FW1y+J/YA9dUrAC39ITejlZWhVIwawkKw==",
      "requires": {
        "core-util-is": "~1.0.0",
        "inherits": "~2.0.3",
        "isarray": "~1.0.0",
        "process-nextick-args": "~2.0.0",
        "safe-buffer": "~5.1.1",
        "string_decoder": "~1.1.1",
        "util-deprecate": "~1.0.1"
      }
    },

    "request": {
      "version": "2.88.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.88.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-NAqBSrijGLZdM0WZNsInLJpkJokL72XYjUpnB0iwsRgxh7dB6COrHnTBNwN0E+lHDAJzu7kLAkDeY08z2/A0hg==",
      "requires": {
        "aws-sign2": "~0.7.0",
        "aws4": "^1.8.0",
        "caseless": "~0.12.0",
        "combined-stream": "~1.0.6",
        "extend": "~3.0.2",
        "forever-agent": "~0.6.1",
        "form-data": "~2.3.2",
        "har-validator": "~5.1.0",
        "http-signature": "~1.2.0",
        "is-typedarray": "~1.0.0",
        "isstream": "~0.1.2",
        "json-stringify-safe": "~5.0.1",
        "mime-types": "~2.1.19",
        "oauth-sign": "~0.9.0",
        "performance-now": "^2.1.0",
        "qs": "~6.5.2",
        "safe-buffer": "^5.1.2",
        "tough-cookie": "~2.4.3",
        "tunnel-agent": "^0.6.0",
        "uuid": "^3.3.2"
      }
    },


    "safe-buffer": {
      "version": "5.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safe-buffer/-/safe-buffer-5.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Gd2UZBJDkXlY7GbJxfsE8/nvKkUEU1G38c1siN6QP6a9PT9MmHB8GnpscSmMJSoF8LOIrt8ud/wPtojys4G6+g=="
    },


    "safer-buffer": {
      "version": "2.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safer-buffer/-/safer-buffer-2.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-YZo3K82SD7Riyi0E1EQPojLz7kpepnSQI9IyPbHHg1XXXevb5dJI7tpyN2ADxGcQbHG7vcyRHk0cbwqcQriUtg=="
    },

    "sshpk": {
      "version": "1.16.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sshpk/-/sshpk-1.16.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-HXXqVUq7+pcKeLqqZj6mHFUMvXtOJt1uoUx09pFW6011inTMxqI8BA8PM95myrIyyKwdnzjdFjLiE6KBPVtJIg==",
      "requires": {
        "asn1": "~0.2.3",
        "assert-plus": "^1.0.0",
        "bcrypt-pbkdf": "^1.0.0",
        "dashdash": "^1.12.0",
        "ecc-jsbn": "~0.1.1",
        "getpass": "^0.1.1",
        "jsbn": "~0.1.0",
        "safer-buffer": "^2.0.2",
        "tweetnacl": "~0.14.0"
      }
    },

    "string_decoder": {
      "version": "1.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder/-/string_decoder-1.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-n/ShnvDi6FHbbVfviro+WojiFzv+s8MPMHBczVePfUpDJLwoLT0ht1l4YwBCbi8pJAveEEdnkHyPyTP/mzRfwg==",
      "requires": {
        "safe-buffer": "~5.1.0"
      }
    },

   "tunnel-agent": {
      "version": "0.6.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent/-/tunnel-agent-0.6.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-J6XeoGs2sEoKmWZ3SykIaPD8QP0=",
      "requires": {
        "safe-buffer": "^5.0.1"
      }
    },
```

Anyone know what I need to do to "upgrade" these references so I am not getting the depreciation warning?

Comment: you don't need to upgrade anything, where you've `new Buffer()`, change to `Buffer.from()` (or `Buffer.alloc()`, if you know your stuff)

Comment: I don't have new Buffer() anywhere in my code. This is the only place it's referenced.

Comment: could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Is this what you're after? 2019-04-18T03:53:52  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
Application: (node:32004) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Comment: somewhere it should probably mention the origin file, etc

Comment: I can't seem to find that, but I did find in the extend-node.js file, a heap of code along these lines. I'm guessing that's what I need to update...  original.BufferWrite = Buffer.prototype.write;
        Buffer.prototype.write = function(string, offset, length, encoding) {

Comment: I'm just curious about buffer packages here, safer-buffer and then safe-buffer are used. I was confused about their version until I found there was an 'r' in the other name :)

Comment: @Kat If my answer is helpful for you, please make it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the warning said

> DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and
>   usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(),
>   or Buffer.from() methods instead.

To avoid the depreciation warning. You need to find out the new Buffer() methods in your codes and replace them with a new one. Such as in the extend-node.js file(`NodeTaskApp-master\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib`), Line 13:

```
iconv.supportsNodeEncodingsExtension = !(Buffer.from || new Buffer(0) instanceof Uint8Array);
```

Comment: I can't see anywhere in the actual app where it uses buffer, just in these modules. Rather than update each line, can I just delete it? There seems to be a lot of modules this app has which it doesn't use. For the ease of my upskilling, maybe I can get rid of them all, and add them back as required?

Comment: Dependencies in my package.json file list     "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "tedious": "^5.0.3", All the others are listed in package-lock.json. Can I just delete all the ones not used in package.json?

Comment: @Kat Yes, you can. But the package-lock.json file is automatically generated. If you reinstall the module, it will come back again.

Comment: @Kat The express dependency will install many modules, you need to confirm you will not use that module before deleting it.

Comment: @Kat Do you have any other concerns regarding this question?

Comment: from our discussions I am now developing locally with visual studio code, and syncing to the azure portal when I am happy with an update. I'm not having the many little bugs I was getting like this, so I think it is a much better setup. Thanks!

Comment: OP has said there are no calls to Buffer() in their code. The Buffer() calls are in installed packages. This answer does not address that.

Comment: I have this very issue, @Kat what was the resolution? deleting every entry that had a buffer in it?